# Split Camunda and UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, camunda

I am new to camunda so bear with with me.
I have an existing application built up using Nodejs and React. I managed to implemented camunda for server-side using the camunda rest api.

As far as my UI is concern it has 10-12 signup steps/workflow which can switch depending on user type. Now I don’t want my React application to be embedded inside camunda. My UI will get instructions from my server and server in-return get the instruction from camunda engine basis on the initialized bpm process. For further clarity this is what I am trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhxghzKMFBg&t=823s

If I can get any pointers/link/sudo code it will be really helpful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses React as Frontend and interacts with camunda via REST: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/camunda-tasklist-examples/camunda-react-app